# Back Button React native exit app

Tags: react-native

I have put android back button exit the app functionality  in my react native app in my home screen. But when I press android back button on other screens then also it is getting called.

```
componentDidMount() {

    if (Platform.OS == "android") {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);                           
  }
    this._setupGoogleSignin();           
    this._getUserDetails();
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log("object url is", this.state.postsArray[0].url);

}

handleBackButton = () => {               
    Alert.alert(
        'Exit App',
        'Exiting the application?', [{
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
            style: 'cancel'
        }, {
            text: 'OK',
            onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
        }, ], {
            cancelable: false
        }
     )
     return true;
   }
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253072/react-native-double-back-press-to-exit-app

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your HomeScreen is still mounted when you navigate to other screens or while unmounting the `HomeScreen` if you don't remove the EventListener it will be still called.

You should clear the EventListener on navigate or unmount,

```
onButtonPress = () => {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  // then navigate
  navigate('NewScreen');
}

handleBackButton = () => {
 Alert.alert(
     'Exit App',
     'Exiting the application?', [{
         text: 'Cancel',
         onPress: () = > console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
         style: 'cancel'
     }, {
         text: 'OK',
         onPress: () = > BackHandler.exitApp()
     }, ], {
         cancelable: false
     }
  )
  return true;
} 

componentDidMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}
```

Comment: @ParasWatts Can you update your question with the code you tried please.

Comment: Home screen is my main screen which opens when I open the app. So want to exit from app when I click hardware back button. I have updated the code

Comment: @ParasWatts like I said in my answer, HomeScreen is not unmounting I believe. If you are pushing screens to the stack, HomeScreen will be still mounted so your `removeEventListener` is not ever calling. Try removing the listener before navigating to another screen.

Comment: There is one issue, I Have a drawer, from which I am navigating to other screens , drawer is getting rendered in some other file and navigation code is also in that file. Home screen is rendering that drawer component, but onpress navigation is in sidebar file which makes the drawer. How do I handle this situation ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @bennygenel

Comment: @ParasWatts if your navigation logic is in Drawer component then you can move the backButton listeners to the Drawer component too. This way you can control it in all app.

Comment: It worked in doing it in home screen only as i have used a function to bind navigation in home screen with drawer component

Comment: @ParasWatts if it works no problem but if you didn't already added you might need to handle the situation where user lands on HomeScreen goes to another screen and comes back to HomeScreen.

Comment: It will asking for exit. on all nested navigator screens but required in home screen only any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want the Alert message to appear in other component/screen but only in one specific component/screen, you can follow this.

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class TestComponent extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  handleBackButton = () => {
    if (this.props.isFocused) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Exit App',
        'Exiting the application?',
        [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
            style: 'cancel'
          },
          {
            text: 'OK',
            onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
          }
        ],
        {
          cancelable: false
        }
      );
      return true;
    }
  };
} 

export default withNavigationFocus(TestComponent );
```

The BackHandler that will show an Alert message will only work in TestComponent

Comment: This worked but i realized that when i load the App without Navigating to any screen, the application would exit without Trigering the Alert, but when i navigate within the app and come back to the main-view-screen the Alert trigger would appear.

So how can i trigger the Alert on the Main-View-Screen without navigating to other screens first.

Any suggestion would be OK

Answer (score 4):

We can add ***subscriptions*** for ***didfocus*** inside our main App Container.We can add our logic to check for button tapped with a ***static variable***.

```
import {  Alert,  BackHandler,  ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import {  StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { Toast } from 'native-base';
// common statless class variable.
let backHandlerClickCount = 0;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // add listener to didFocus
      this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload =>
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.onBackButtonPressAndroid(payload)));
    }

    // remove listener on unmount 
    componentWillUnmount() {
      if (this._didFocusSubscription) {
        this._didFocusSubscription.remove();
      }
    }

    onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
      const shortToast = message => {
        // ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(
        //     message,
        //     ToastAndroid.SHORT,
        //     ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
        //     25,
        //     50
        // );

        // ios & android
        Toast.show({
            text: message,
            type: 'warning',
            position: 'top',
            duration: 3000,
        });
        }

        const {
          clickedPosition
        } = this.state;
        backHandlerClickCount += 1;
        if ((clickedPosition !== 1)) {
          if ((backHandlerClickCount < 2)) {
            shortToast('Press again to quit the application!');
          } else {
            BackHandler.exitApp();
          }
        }

        // timeout for fade and exit
        setTimeout(() => {
          backHandlerClickCount = 0;
        }, 2000);

        if (((clickedPosition === 1) &&
            (this.props.navigation.isFocused()))) {
          Alert.alert(
            'Exit Application',
            'Do you want to quit application?', [{
              text: 'Cancel',
              onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
              style: 'cancel'
            }, {
              text: 'OK',
              onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
            }], {
              cancelable: false
            }
          );
        } else {
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop({
            n: 1
          }));
        }
        return true;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to double back press to Exit App

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';

let backHandlerClickCount = 0;

const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // back handle exit app
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backButtonHandler);
        return () => {
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backButtonHandler);
        };
    }, []);
    const backButtonHandler = () => {
        const shortToast = message => {
            Toast.show(message, {
                duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
                position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
            });
        }
        let backHandlerClickCount;
        backHandlerClickCount += 1;
        if ((backHandlerClickCount < 2)) {
            shortToast('Press again to quit the application');
        } else {
            BackHandler.exitApp();
        }

        // timeout for fade and exit
        setTimeout(() => {
            backHandlerClickCount = 0;
        }, 1000);
        
        return true;
    }
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
         ....
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to other answers

If you are using `'@react-navigation/native'` then setting eventListner on backButton will work even when you have navigated to child screens. To overcome this set eventListner on `focus` rather than with `componentDidMount()` and remove it when `blur` event occurs on screen.

[Learn more about react-navigation events here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

```
export class sampleScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        foo: '',
        bar: '',
    };

    this._unsubscribeSiFocus = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', e => {
        console.warn('focus signIn');
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    });
    this._unsubscribeSiBlur = this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', e => {
        console.warn('blur signIn');
        BackHandler.removeEventListener(
            'hardwareBackPress',
            this.handleBackButton,
        );
    });

    onButtonPress = () => {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener(
            'hardwareBackPress',
            this.handleBackButton,
        );
    };
}

handleBackButton = () => {
    Alert.alert(
        'Exit App',
        'Exiting the application?',
        [{
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
                text: 'OK',
                onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp(),
            },
        ], {
            cancelable: false,
        },
    );
    return true;
};

componentDidMount() {
    // BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribeSiFocus();
    this._unsubscribeSiBlur();
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}
```

}

Comment: This approach was quite helpful since I have a number of stack inside the `Home` stack. However, I am facing issue with my `Sign Out` which will navigate to the `Login Page`. I am getting `this._unsubscribeSiFocus is not a function` error. NOTE: The `Login Page` is outside my `Home` stack which is essentially wrapped in a `Drawer Navigator`

Comment: Work around: Load the complete stack on Sign Out (since it starts with the Login page). It was easier for me since the hierarchy of all stacks are defined in a single file.

Comment: @TusharGautam you nailed it brother. I think this should the perfect answer.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Guyz please do understand it might not only be the problem with react native. Be careful while integrating it with firebase. The recent firebase version has the problem of integrating back button in react-native apps!! Please downgrade the firebase version to firebase-version @5.0.3 and then recheck whether it works or not! I had the same issue and was worried for days. I finally downgraded to @5.0.3 version and now the back button works perfectly fine! You may downgrade to lower versions if still facing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always dynamically modify what the callback function for the `BackHandler.addEventListener` is based on the current scene (using `react-native-router-flux` makes this easy).

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

handleBackPress = () => {
 switch (Actions.currentScene) {
   case 'home':
     BackHandler.exitApp()
     break

   default: Actions.pop()
 }

 return true
}
```

The full gist can be found here: https://gist.github.com/omeileo/f05a068557e9f0a2d8a24ecccd2f3177

Answer (score 0):

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
    Alert.alert(
      'Thoát Khỏi Ứng Dụng',
      'Bạn có muốn thoát không?', [{
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel'
      }, {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
      }, ], {
          cancelable: false
      }
   )
   return true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with this issue, but I managed to solve it in this quite simple way. I am using react-navigation 4.4.1.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BackHandler, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {
        canBeClosed: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }
      
    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }

    handleBackButton = () => {
        if (this.props.navigation.isFocused()) {
            if (this.state.canBeClosed)
                return this.state.canBeClosed = false;
    
            else {
                setTimeout(() => { this.state.canBeClosed = false }, 3000);    
                ToastAndroid.show("Press Again To Exit !", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    
                return this.state.canBeClosed = true
            }   
        }
    };

 //some code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for Back Press in Functional Components.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
        return () => {
            // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
        }
    }, [])

    onButtonPress = () => {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
        // then navigate
        //navigate('NewScreen');
    }
      
    const handleBackButton = () => {
        BackHandler.exitApp();
        return true;
    }
```