# React Native Android BackHandler Exit App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to implement the BackHandler to run on one component and keep the default behavior of the hardware back button 'go to the previous screen' in the rest of my app, I have a component named 'cases.js' I want to exit the app if the user clicked the back button while this component is in the screen and to navigate back if the user is on any other component, the cases screen lays over the Login screen.

Here is what I've tried in 'cases.js' file:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {

    await BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._closeApp())

  }

  componentWillUnmount = async () => {

    await BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this_closeApp());

  }

  _closeApp = async () => {

    BackHandler.exitApp();

  }
```

but it keeps closing the app immediately.

How may I achieve that?

Comment: Does this screen gets mounted when you start the app? Or it is not yet pushed in the stack?

Comment: I check while the splash screen is on display wether the user has a token or not and redirect him to either this component or the login component

Comment: So when you are in login eg, it closes the app and it should return you to previous screen right?

Comment: No, when i' logged in i don't want to go back to the login screen i want to exit the app .. otherwise i want the back button to redirect to the previous page

Comment: How are you mounting the screens? Just do a replace/reset depends on the navigation library documentation you are using so you set the root screen. Than you don't need any changes with the backhandler

Comment: Example: When the user successfully completes on boarding, we reset him to table of content so when he presses back there there is no more screens in the stack because table of content is the root screen now.

Comment: exactly .. that's what i want to achieve ..

Comment: What navigation library are you using?

Comment: react-navigation

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with it, but as I googled for docs related to reset stack I did found some snippets how to achieve this. Try looking for reset stack in the docs.

Comment: i will, thanks for your help .. 

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I can't add comments yet - adding to Mahdi Bashirpour's answer, which is correct:

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton = () => {
    //add your code

    return true;
};
```

This code will work, but as you noticed, once you add EventListener on Login screen it will affect all other screens deeper in the stack that do not overwrite BackHandler EventListener.

The best way to solve this is to add another condition that checks that you are in Login screen:

```
handleBackButton = () => {
    if (screen == 'Login') {
    BackHandler.exitApp();
    return true;
    }
};
```

How to check which screen you are on? Assuming you are using React-Navigation take a look [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html).
If you are having problems tracking the current screen I suggest opening a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return true;` to `_closeApp` method

```
_closeApp = async () => {

    // BackHandler.exitApp();

    return true;
}
```

This link can help you a lot: 
[React Native: Double back press to Exit App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253072/react-native-double-back-press-to-exit-app/52253073)

Comment: it's giving me error "Object is not a function (evaluating 'subscriptions[i]()') !

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton = () => {
    //add your code

    return true;
};
```

Comment: now it's exiting the app from any component ! i added `BackHandler.exitApp()` and it's running on every component i go to